# LaTeX signature image on line with text beneath

Tags: templates, latex

i try to make a signature inside a latex template with a hand written signature image from a png. I like to place it on a line with the name as text beneath. I've tried to make it with a table, but i failed to place it directly on the line. I hope someone can help me here.

I uploaded a example image how it should look like: [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uknUL.jpg)

Comment: You might get better help here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See [Adding a signature on an online job application](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32911/5764).